# Vuejs - Watcher not watching deep enough

Tags: vue.js, watch

For some reason, Vuejs doesn't deeply watch for changes. Let's say below is the data that I'm watching.

```
input_collection: [
    {
        type: 'foo',
        value: 'foo'
    },{
        type: 'bar',
        value: 'bar'
    },{
        type: 'baz',
        value: 'baz'
    }
]
```

Basically its an array of objects. When I change anything except the last item, it triggers the watch to do its job. But when the last item is updated, it doesn't.

The way that I change the contents of the `input_collection` is by using `v-model` and directly changing the value in the code. I'm also suspecting the direct change method as a culprit since i only used this in the last item and the input has a read-only attribute, but since I'm directly assigning a new value for the item's content, that shouldn't be a problem.

```
//via v-model
<input :type="type" v-model="title"/>

//via directly changing
<input type="type" :value="value" readonly>
//js
this.input.title = new_value;
this.value = new_value;
```

I tried manually changing the last contents in the last item's content via the Vue Devtools Extension but it still doesn't work.

Comment: We require a [mcve] to properly answer this question, in particular *what* you are watching, *how* you set the initial data and the steps you take to reproduce a situation where you do no longer see changes in your watcher. Without that information, I can only vaguely guess what the problem is.

Comment: post have been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Turns out that it being `readonly` is causing my problems.
I just created a work around to it by doing:

```
//markup
<input type="text" v-model="input.value" @keypress.prevent>
//js
this.input.value = new_value
```

Now, the watcher works as it should be.